# How do I control the amount of duplicate values in my list

Tags: python

I need a condition or an if statement that makes sure the user input can only input the maximum of 5 per type of item in a list. For example, let's say there is a menu where you can pick items to buy but there is a maximum limit of 5 of the same type of item you can purchase at once. 
I can only buy let's say 5 Mango smoothies but not 6. 
But I can also buy say 5 Mango smoothies and 1 Strawberry smoothie 
What I'm trying to say is 5 is not the maximum number of items you can buy but the maximum number of the same type of items you can buy. I need this condition to make sure the 6th duplicate item by the user input doesn't get appended to my list.

```
#This is what my list should allow
my_list = [["Mango", 2.00], ["Mango", 2.00], ["Mango", 2.00], ["Mango", 2.00], ["Mango", 2.00], ["Strawberry", 2.00]]

#This is what my list shouldn't allow 
my_list = [["Mango", 2.00], ["Mango", 2.00], ["Mango", 2.00], ["Mango", 2.00], ["Mango", 2.00], ["Mango", 2.00], ["Strawberry", 2.00]]
```

Comment: Why repeat things in a list? Just use a dictionary with counts: `basket = {'Mango': 5, 'Strawberry': 1}`. Keep prices separate from this.

Comment: What's `2.00`? Is it the price or a quantity?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment by @Martijn Pieters.
But if you have any reason to do it in your way, here's my solution:

```
my_list = [["Mango", 2.00], ["Mango", 2.00], ["Mango", 2.00], ["Mango", 2.00], ["Mango", 2.00], ["Strawberry", 2.00]]
product_cache = {}
for obj in my_list:
    if obj[0] in product_cache:
        product_cache[obj[0]]+=1
        if product_cache[obj[0]] > 5:
            print( str(obj[0]) + ' over 5')
            #do something
    else:
        product_cache[obj[0]] = 1
```

and "product_cache" will be the dict @Martijn Pieters said

```
product_cache = {'Strawberry': 1 , 'Mango': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the number of occurences of each item, and check that no item appears more than 5 times:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_list = [["Mango", 2.00], ["Mango", 2.00], ["Mango", 2.00], ["Mango", 2.00], ["Mango", 2.00], ["Strawberry", 2.00]]
>>> Counter(item for item,_ in my_list)
Counter({'Mango': 5, 'Strawberry': 1})
>>> Counter(item for item,_ in my_list).values()
dict_values([5, 1])
>>> max(Counter(item for item,_ in my_list).values())
5
>>> max(Counter(item for item,_ in my_list).values()) <= 5
True
```